# Can't understand what queries using through model do in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Goal(Model):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    # title of the goal
    title = CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), max_length=256)

    children = ManyToManyField('self', through='DecompositionGoal', symmetrical=False)


class DecompositionGoal(Model):
    id = UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    parent = ForeignKey(Goal, related_name='related_src')
    child = ForeignKey(Goal, related_name='related_dst')

    is_accepted = BooleanField(default=False)
```

For a given goal I'm trying to find all children goals that are accepted.
I ended up with `goal.children.filter(related_dst__is_accepted=True)`.

But just for curiosity what does the following selects: `goal.children.filter(related_src__is_accepted=True)`?

Can somebody explain all this works when using through model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for your goals children you are filtering out if their parent (original goal) is accepted, so you would get all the children if parent node is accepted, or none if parent node is not accepted